# Is there a DRY way to edit viewmodels and their individual component models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, dry

I would like to edit the `DinnerViewModel` (below) as a single unit.

I'd also like to edit the component models `Drink`, `MainCourse` and `Dessert` individually.

*And I'd like to use the same razor views for both.*

```
public class DinnerViewModel
{
    public Drink Drink {get;set;}
    public MainCourse MainCourse {get;set;}
    public Dessert Dessert {get;set;}
}
```

**Displaying Fields to Edit**

This seems to work ok:

```
@model EditDinnerViewModel

@{Html.RenderPartial("_DrinkEditingFields", Model.Drink);}
@{Html.RenderPartial("_MainCourseEditingFields", Model.MainCourse );}
@{Html.RenderPartial("_DessertEditingFields", Model.Dessert );}
```

**Posting to Controller**

This is where I'm having trouble. I would like to do this:

```
public ActionResult CreateDinner(DinnerViewModel dinner)
```

But because I've rendered each viewmodel component as a partial, it won't bind properly. (E.g. field names are just `Veg` and `Meat` as opposed to `MainCourse_Veg` and `MainCourse_Meat`).

I expect I could get it working like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateDinner(Drink drink, MainCourse mainCourse, Dessert dessert)
```

But surely this is bad design (for example if 2 models shared the same field name, I'd be in trouble).

*I think this is probably a common requirement. How would an experienced developer approach this?*

Comment: Use editor templates rather than partial views.

Comment: So simple!. I had thought they were just for single properties, I didn't realise you could use them for whole models. Thanks Dom. If you put that into an answer I'll mark it as such

Comment: You can also use [`UIHintAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to declaratively influence which editor template your model should use for a property.

Answer (score 0):

@Dom's answer is absolutely correct "Use editor templates rather than partial views".
Also if you (for some reasons) want to use a specific prefix for your components use:

```
@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Prefix";
}
```